# Can't get process start variables

Tags: camunda

I'm trying to get process start variables via rest, but I can't receive any start variable.

When i try:

```
http://192.168.30.1:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/key/invoice/form-variables
```

I got only this:

```
{}
```

How to get process start variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the resource [Get Start Form Variables](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/rest/process-definition/get-form-variables/) only supports [Generated Start Forms](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/user-guide/task-forms/#generated-task-forms).

The invoice process uses [Embedded Start Form](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/user-guide/task-forms/#embedded-task-forms). The start event of the invoice process references an external HTML file, which is used to render the Start form.

See [here](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/examples/invoice/src/main/resources/invoice.v1.bpmn#L66-L68):

```
<startEvent id="StartEvent_1" name="Invoice&#10;received" camunda:formKey="embedded:app:forms/start-form.html">
  <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1</outgoing>
</startEvent>
```

If you want to receive the start form variables, the start event of the process must be look like the following example:

```
<startEvent id="start">
  <extensionElements>
    <camunda:formData>
      <camunda:formField id="stringField" label="String Field" type="string" defaultValue="someString">
        <camunda:validation>
          <camunda:constraint name="maxlength" config="10" />
          <camunda:constraint name="minlength" config="5" />
        </camunda:validation>
      </camunda:formField>
      <camunda:formField id="longField" label="Long Field" type="long" defaultValue="5">
        <camunda:validation>
          <camunda:constraint name="max" config="10" />
          <camunda:constraint name="min" config="3" />
        </camunda:validation>
      </camunda:formField>
      <camunda:formField id="customField" label="Custom Field" type="string">
        <camunda:validation>
          <camunda:constraint name="validator" config="org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.api.form.CustomValidator" />
        </camunda:validation>
      </camunda:formField>
      <camunda:formField id="dateField" label="Date Field" type="date" defaultValue="10/01/2013" />
    </camunda:formData>
  </extensionElements>
</startEvent>
```

See [here](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/test/resources/org/camunda/bpm/engine/test/api/form/FormServiceTest.startFormFields.bpmn20.xml) for the complete example process.
In that case the FormService can resolve the form variables and the request will return the defined variables.